# parse out string, set it as a factor column in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I can not really find an elegant way achieving this, please help.

I have a `DT` data.table:

```
name,value
"lorem pear ipsum",4
"apple ipsum lorem",2
"lorem ipsum plum",6
```

And based on a list `Fruits <- c("pear", "apple", "plum")` I'd like to create a factor type column.

```
name,value,factor
"lorem pear ipsum",4,"pear"
"apple ipsum lorem",2,"apple"
"lorem ipsum plum",6,"plum"
```

I guess that's basic, but I'm kinda stuck, this is how far I got:

`DT[grep("apple", name, ignore.case=TRUE), factor := as.factor("apple")]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess I need to replace the `as.factor("apple")` part with a custom function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can vectorize this with regular expressions, e.g. by using `gsub()`:

Set up the data:

```
strings <- c("lorem pear ipsum", "apple ipsum lorem", "lorem ipsum plum")
fruit <- c("pear", "apple", "plum")
```

Now create a regular expression

```
ptn <- paste0(".*(", paste(fruit, collapse="|"), ").*")
gsub(ptn, "\\1", strings)
[1] "pear"  "apple" "plum"
```

---

The regular expression works by separating each search element with `|`, embedded inside parentheses:

```
ptn
[1] ".*(pear|apple|plum).*"
```

---

To do this inside a data table, as per your question is then as simple as:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(name=strings, value=c(4, 2, 6))
DT[, factor:=gsub(ptn, "\\1", strings)]
DT

                name value factor
1:  lorem pear ipsum     4   pear
2: apple ipsum lorem     2  apple
3:  lorem ipsum plum     6   plum
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if there is a more "data.table" way to do it, but you can try this:

```
DT[, factor := sapply(Fruits, function(x) Fruits[grep(x, name, ignore.case=TRUE)])]
DT
#                 name value factor
# 1:  lorem pear ipsum     4   pear
# 2: apple ipsum lorem     2  apple
# 3:  lorem ipsum plum     6   plum
```

Comment: (+1) This is not essentially a "typical" `data.table` problem, I'd say.

Comment: It might be me, but this code fills up the `DT$factor` column with DT-long lists like `c(NA,NA,"pear",NA,"apple",...)`. I'm investigating further, I'm sure that your hint (sapply) will lead me to the solution.

Comment: @NyitraiLőrinc, I'm suspecting then that your mini data example isn't accurately reflective of the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my coded solution. The hard part is getting the matched string from `regex`. The best general solution (that finds whatever is matched to any regular expression) I know of is the `regexec` and `regmatches` combination (see below).

```
# Create the data frame
name <- c("lorem pear ipsum", "apple ipsum lorem", "lorem ipsum plum")
value <- c(4,2,6)
DT <- data.frame(name=name, value=value, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Create the regular expression
Fruits <- c("pear", "apple", "plum")
myRegEx <- paste(Fruits, collapse = "|")

# Find the matches
r <- regexec(myRegEx, DT$name, ignore.case = TRUE)
matches <- regmatches(DT$name, r)

# Extract the matches, convert to factors
factor <- sapply(matches, function(x) as.factor(x[[1]]))

# Add to data frame
DT$factor <- factor
```

This is probably a longer solution than you wanted.